# How to delete all files and sub-directorys from a dir without delete the dir in Windows CMD?

Tags: cmd, directory, rmdir

Hi I'm looking for a command similar to this command in Linux:

rm -fRv debug/*

This command delete all files and directories that is inside debug but without delete the debug directory.

How can I do this in Windows with CMD ?

bye

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
for /d %x in (debug\*) do @rd /s /q "%x"
del /s /f /q debug\*
```

Comment: rd /s /q debug\* - doesn't work. It's tells "The command syntax is wrong."

Comment: this is the most weird sintax to a simple command that I ever seen. But it's works. Thanks

Comment: @user: Historically there has been a distinction between deleting a directory and a file (back to the old DOS days which is what CMD was based on (and CP/M before that)). So what this is doing here is iterate over all directories (`for /d`) and for each of them issue a `rd` command (since `rd` cannot accept wildcards, as you noticed). Then we proceed with deleting all normal files in that directory (`del debug\*`). The easier (and likely faster way) would probably be to delete `debug` and re-create it, but of course that cannot work if some process still has that as its working directory.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to for me:

```
del /S /Q debug\*
```

(Though, off-topic, I'm using the MinGW `rm` command, which works just the same as under Linux.)

Comment: del /S /Q debug\* - this command deletes only files.. the sub-directories remains intact. How can I use the MinGw rm command inside of a Qt project files (.pro) ?

Comment: I don't know anything about Qt project files, but since the question was about CMD, I assume they run as scrips. The rm that you can get from MinGW or from GnuWin32 or Unxutils (whichever you want) is just a plain normal "command" program in the Unix sense. So, as long as it's in %PATH% you can just call it from any script.

Comment: hmm.. I understand, but I can't find any file called rm.exe (or similar) in my Qt installation MinGW.

Comment: Funny, I very clearly have all the "standard" unix programs here, though admittedly some may have come from Unxutils or GnuWin32. Though I think that the MinGW/MSYS packages include the most basic commands like `ls` or `rm`, too. In any case, you can always find those in UnxUtils.